# Rubberband  Effect on Image using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, adorner, rubber-band

I am trying to watermark an Image and works perfect and now I need to have my customers much more convinient so that I am planning to add a feasibility to the image watermarker.So I need some help!

I want to have an adorner control or somethng like the rubberband effect which has 4 0r 6 corners so that they can enlarge the text with that.

I have seen one of the articles in codeproject which is implemented with WPF as shown below.But I need to implement with my normal ASP.Net application.So how do I start with it?

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: this is not trivial at all. Do you want to do it with Javascript?

Comment: Yes if it's possible to add I would like to know but I need to add text control in that.

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:

http://html5.litten.com/moving-shapes-on-the-html5-canvas-with-the-keyboard/

with pure HTML5 canvas and JavaScript you can move a shape using the keyboard.

it's a starting point then you can imagine to extend it to support mouse gestures like you explained.